# Removing Nodes in XML

Tags: xml, e4x

I'm a newbie to manipulating xml and hope i can get some help from you all.

My back end system spits out an XML file with the following node structer.

```
<orders xmlns="http://www.foo.com/xml/impex/order/">
<order order-no="0000000000000303">
<order-date>2011-09-02T18:55:00.000Z</order-date>
<created-by>foo</created-by>
<original-order-no>0000000000000303</original-order-no>
<currency>USD</currency>
<customer-locale>default</customer-locale>
<affiliate-partner-name/>
<affiliate-partner-id/>
<invoice-no>00001422</invoice-no>
<customer>...</customer>
<customer-order-reference/>
<status>...</status>
<replace-code/>
<replace-description/>
<replacement-order-no/>
<replaced-order-no/>
<current-order-no>0000000000000303</current-order-no>
<cancel-code/>
<cancel-description/>
<product-lineitems>...</product-lineitems>
<giftcertificate-lineitems/>
<shipping-lineitems>...</shipping-lineitems>
<shipments>...</shipments>
<totals>...</totals>
<payments>
<payment>
<gift-certificate>
<custom-attributes>
<custom-attribute attribute-id="giftCard01Number">01000169466975</custom-attribute>
<custom-attribute attribute-id="giftCard01Value">10.00</custom-attribute>
<custom-attribute attribute-id="giftCard02Number">01100995910</custom-attribute>
<custom-attribute attribute-id="giftCard02Value">20.00</custom-attribute>
<custom-attribute attribute-id="giftCertificateType">card</custom-attribute>
</custom-attributes>
</gift-certificate>
<amount>10.00</amount>
<processor-id>BARNEYS_GIFT_CARD</processor-id>
<transaction-id>0000000000000303</transaction-id>
</payment>
<payment>
<gift-certificate>
<custom-attributes>
<custom-attribute attribute-id="giftCard02Number">01100995910</custom-attribute>
<custom-attribute attribute-id="giftCard02Value">20.00</custom-attribute>
<custom-attribute attribute-id="giftCertificateType">card</custom-attribute>
</custom-attributes>
</gift-certificate>
<processor-id>BARNEYS_GIFT_CARD</processor-id>
</payment>
<payment>
<credit-card>...</credit-card>
<amount>35.33</amount>
<processor-id>VCOMMERCE_CREDIT</processor-id>
<transaction-id>0000000000000303</transaction-id>
<custom-attributes>...</custom-attributes>
</payment>
</payments>
<remoteHost/>
<external-order-no/>
<external-order-status/>
<external-order-text/>
<custom-attributes>...</custom-attributes>
</order>
</orders>
```

Now The part that need to change is the order Node.
The data that needs to be kept are the first and last payment nodes.
Any other node that falls in the middle of that can be removed or deleted.
Is there a way with E4x to do this?

Thanks for all your help.
Berto

Comment: What is "reming"? Do you mean renaming? Removing?

Comment: Why do you need to use E4X? You mentioned that the XML file is generated on the back-end, so are you not able to use a back-end language/technology to manipulate the XML file?

Comment: What if there are 2 payment nodes? Do you remove first and last? In order words do you remove both of them?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about E4X, but using [Rhino](http://www.mozilla.org/rhino/), [Envjs](http://www.envjs.com/) and [jQuery](http://jquery.com/):

Start Rhino:

```
java -jar js.jar -opt -1
```

Now you should be at the Rhino prompt.

Load some libraries (I don't recommend loading from the internet, but for the purposes of an example), read the orders file, parse into xml, remove the payments, then print out the result...

```
load("http://www.envjs.com/dist/env.rhino.1.2.js")
load("https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js")
load("../rhino-scripts/removeFirstAndLastPayments.js")
xmlstr = readFile("../rhino-scripts/orders.xml")
xml = $.parseXML(xmlstr)
removeFirstAndLastPayments(xml)
new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(xml)
```

Where "removeFirstAndLastPayments" is defined as:

```
function removeFirstAndLastPayments(root) {
    $(root).find("orders order").each(function (orderIdx, order) {
        var payments = $(order).find("payment");
        if (payments.length > 2) {
            // only remove first and last if there are more than 2 payments
            payments.first().remove();
            payments.last().remove();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Paul,
Thanks for getting back to me.
I will give it a try.
and let you know.
Cheers
Berto